# How to avoid duplication of data using feeds module?

Tags: feeds

I've set up a CSV importer using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. My CSV is not a drupal file but one that i have, of my own. I've mapped the name of the coupon(a column in my CSV file) onto the title of my content type "coupon". This is just a test run. On importing the same data twice, it's being duplicated. I want the repetitive data to be deleted. Can someone help please?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not really possible now, because Feeds does not respect any kind of universal data ID to know when to update and when to add. There was [requests to add UUID to feeds](https://www.drupal.org/node/1800730), but until then, you will be forced to fall back to less reliable methods. Some discussion is also [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1286424). I know that's not an answer, I hope it'll push you in right direction, or help somebody to answer. Too big task for me now.

Comment: thanks @Mołot
My problem is a bit different as my file is not a drupal file. I just added that bit of info into my question.
But thanks anyway! It sure has given me a way forward =)

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. If you have a column that is unique key, it should be possible to do "on duplicate key, update". But I cannot remember how. If I'll recall, I'll answer.

Comment: Oh okay. Please do!

Answer (score 1):

Use Target configuration as unique to avoid duplication

[image: Title as unique]

Comment: Thanks alot @Rituraj Kumar
I did try that earlier on- didn't work, but just now, it did!